# Export result of glht to LaTeX in R

Tags: r, latex

I want to export the result of a `glht` object in R into a LaTeX table.

For example with the library "stargazer" one can produce a pretty formatted LaTeX table of a `lme` object.

I want have a automatically created LaTeX table from the output of the summary of the `glht` object, such as the summary created with

```
>summary(glht(dataModel))
Linear Hypotheses:
                                                                        Estimate Std.     Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
Group1 - Group2 == 0   -0.14007    0.01589  -8.813   <0.001 "***"
Group1 - Group3 == 0    -0.09396    0.01575  -5.965   <0.001 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

I'm aware of libraries like `stargazer`, `xtable`, `texreg`, `reporttools`, `memisc` and `apsrtable`, but none of them does the job for glht :(

any hints on whether there's a library for that?

Comment: That output does not look to be sufficiently regular to all go into a table. Shouldn't you be separating the regular portions from the heading and annotations?

Comment: well I'm not asking how to format the table, I'm asking whether there's a library which does the job for me

Comment: Produce code that creates a particular object and request assistance in looking at the print method for that object to see how it could be modified to do whatever you are requesting, which seems rather imprecise to me at the moment.

Comment: FYI, it's bad form to cross post to R-help - choose SO or R-help.  Otherwise answers and requests for clarifications get confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might find the answer right in the code example below:

```
multcomp:::print.summary.glht 

x<-glht(...)    
pq<-summary(x)$test

mtests <- cbind(pq$coefficients, pq$sigma, pq$tstat, pq$pvalues)
error <- attr(pq$pvalues, "error")
pname <- switch(x$alternativ, 
                 less = paste("Pr(<", ifelse(x$df ==0, "z", "t"), ")", sep = ""), 
                 greater = paste("Pr(>", ifelse(x$df == 0, "z", "t"), ")", sep = ""), 
                 two.sided = paste("Pr(>|", ifelse(x$df == 0, "z", "t"), "|)", sep = ""))                                                                   
colnames(mtests) <- c("Estimate", "Std. Error", ifelse(x$df ==0, "z value", "t value"), pname)

xtable(mtests)
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could elaborate your answer a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Rich from R-help gave the helping clue:

The trick for latexing glht objects is recognizing that they are very complex.
It is necessary to isolate the part you want first,
then the latex() function in Hmisc works very well.

This example is based on one of the examples in ?glht

```
library(Hmisc)
library(multcomp)

### set up a one-way ANOVA
amod <- aov(breaks ~ tension, data = warpbreaks)

### set up all-pair comparisons for factor `tension'
### using a symbolic description (`type' argument
### to `contrMat()')
amod.glht <- glht(amod, linfct = mcp(tension = "Tukey"))

latex(confint(amod.glht)$confint, dec=3)
```

Well that doesn't print exactly what summary(amod.glht) would print, yet, but latex() is the missing function I was looking for

Comment: `confint(amod.glht)$confint` is an ordinary matrix, so you don't need `Hmisc` (`xtable` is enough).